# WebSocketException on Android 9 when using firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, ssl, firebase-realtime-database, android-9.0-pie

I'm using the standard way to connect to firebase realtime database, using `16.1.0` version of the SDK.

#### Problem:

The connection is setup perfectly fine for devices below Android 9, but for devices running android 9 on mobile network, the firebase connection fails.

It appears to be a `WebSocketException` while connecting to the firebase backend, and followed by an SSL handshake exception, logs:

> D/WebSocket: ws_16 - WebSocket error.
>       com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketException: error while creating secure socket to ...

and:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to s-usc1c-nss-243.firebaseio.com/ (port 443) from /:: (port 42580): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

verbose logs:

> D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
>       D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
>       D/Connection: conn_19 - Opening a connection
>       D/WebSocket: ws_19 - timed out on connect
>       D/WebSocket: ws_19 - closed
>       D/WebSocket: ws_19 - closing itself
>       D/Connection: conn_19 - Realtime connection failed
>       D/Connection: conn_19 - closing realtime connection
>       D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
>       D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
>       D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 2357ms
>       D/WebSocket: ws_19 - WebSocket error.

The SSL certificate behaviour was changed for Android 9, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426755/ssl-certificate-pinning-not-working-anymore-on-android-9), hence i believe it could be an issue which firebase can be resolved from the firebase's end, but not sure.

GitHub issue for the same, [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/124)

Is anyone else facing this issue? Is there a possible hack to this?

PS: The thing works perfectly fine when switched to WiFi, it simply fails at the connection level for P.

#### Edit 1:

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'

// other standard default config code
dependencies{
    implementation deps.firebase.core
    implementation deps.firebase.auth
    implementation deps.firebase.config
    implementation deps.firebase.firestore
    implementation deps.firebase.performance
    implementation deps.firebase.messaging
    implementation deps.firebase.database
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    ext.realm_version = '5.8.0'
    ext.versions = [
   'firebaseCore'           : '16.0.8',
            'firebaseAuth'           : '16.2.0',
            'firebaseConfig'         : '16.4.0',
            'firebasePerf'           : '16.2.4',
            'firestore'              : '18.1.0',
            'firebaseMessaging'      : '17.4.0',
            'firebaseDatabase'       : '16.1.0',
          ]

    ext.deps = [
    'firebase'               : [
                    'core'       : "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${versions.firebaseCore}",
                    'auth'       : "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${versions.firebaseAuth}",
                    'config'     : "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${versions.firebaseConfig}",
                    'firestore'  : "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:${versions.firestore}",
                    'performance': "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:${versions.firebasePerf}",
                    'messaging'  : "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${versions.firebaseMessaging}",
                    'database'   : "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${versions.firebaseDatabase}",
            ]
        ]
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        // r8 tools deps is for CT.
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.3.52'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.9.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please share build.gradle file ?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed what part of it do you wish to see? And which one, App or root build.gradle?

Comment: Both if possible?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed updated with snippets from both the gradle files